# Реализация scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать чтобы скролл доходил точно до того блока с которого выезжал?

[image: введите сюда описание изобраssжения]

- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(".reviews-tab-items-content").on('click', function (e) {
    if (screen.width <= 991) {
        console.log('111111111111111111111');
        if (!$(this).find('.hidden-text').is(':visible')) {
            $(".hidden-text").hide('slow');
            $(this).find(".hidden-text").show('slow');
        } else {
            $(".hidden-text").hide('slow');
        }
        $('.hidden-text').click(function(e){
        $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $('.reviews-tab-items-content').offset().top }, 1000);
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Сохраняйте позицию при открытии, возвращайте туда при закрытии

Comment: @lazyproger, Спасибо! Можете пожалуйста привести пример.